# Напечатать символ N раз подряд

Tags: bash, соревнование

Нужно напечатать в bash символ N раз подряд - максимально короткой командой.

Comment: В одну строку или каждый на новой строке?

Comment: в одну строку. Допустим вот так: ===================

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Думаю, что короче не получится:

```
printf '=%.s' {1..100}
```

P.S. Украдено [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5349772/5611260).

Comment: Этот вариант вполне устраивает, только как сделать чтобы после выполнения он переходил на другую строку?) А то пишет дальше все в ту же.

Comment: @Dofri, просто `printf "\n"`. Можно `printf '=%.s' {1..100}; printf "\n"`

Comment: @Dofri: сомневаюсь, что это условие точно определено. Вы не знаете, когда произойдет переполнение, т.к. не знаете ширину конкретного окна терминала. Например, у меня в терминале можно настроить перенос строк.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, так оно просто перенесется и напечатается в несколько строк. У меня 10000 символов печатается нормально. Я их не считал, конечно.

Comment: @andy.37: а, речь о том чтобы после вывода начать новую строку. Понял. Я думал, задача сделать переносы внутри строки.

Comment: А вот получилось короче ))

Comment: Да, речь именно о том чтобы после вывода следующую команду печатать уже на следующей строке) Допустим я хочу напечатать 10 символов и перевести строку.

Comment: @Dofri, думаю, с переводом строки самым коротким будет `printf "=%.s" {1..20}; echo`

Comment: Да, работает ))

Answer (score 3):

myprint.sh:

```
for i in seq (1 $1)
do
   printf "$2"
done
printf "\n"
```

Использовать `bash myprint.sh 10 x` //напечатать `x` 10 раз
Можно, как у @kff:

`printf "$MYCHAR%.s" $(seq $COUNT)`

В {1..N} у меня переменную вставить не получилось.

```
printf "=%.s" $(sec 100)
```

Да, у меня на 2 символа длиннее, чем у @Nick. Но для N=99, будет уже на 1)

Comment: Ваш вариант тоже попробовал, но мне нужен именно короткий :)

Answer (score 2):

Ровно на символ короче, чем [в ответе kff](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/472630/181472), 21 символ =)

```
printf '=%.s' {0..99}
```

Вариант на 22 символа, основан на том, что неопределенные переменные разрешаются как пустая строка.

```
printf "=%.s"$z{0..99}
```

Два варианта с заменой символов, первый придумал сам, второй [позаимствовал](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5349796/2790048).

```
printf %100s | sed 's/ /=/g' #28
printf %100s | tr " " "="    #25
```

Ещё один интересный вариант, работает не во всех шеллах, зато 21 символ.

```
repeat 100 printf "="
```

На большинстве ОС, где есть bash, есть и python:

```
python -c "print '='*100" #25
```

Comment: У Вас будет короче на 1 символ в редких случаях печати ровно 10, 100, 1000 и т.д. символов. )))

Comment: @andy.37: да, верно )